# Getting 'Connection refused' after installing PostgreSQL and PG Admin 4

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I had installed PostgreSQL Server on a machine. I had installed PGAdmin4 on another machine but when trying to connect, I am getting error on the startup of the PG Admin4 'Connection refused'.

How can I get it working?  I have just started using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please show the connection settings, check if PostgreSQL is actually running and if it is, the connection settings actually point to it and not elsewhere.

Comment: And check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit `postgresql.conf` and change `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`
2. Edit `pg_hba.conf` file and add an entry for the IP/network you are connecting from.
   To allow anyone to connect add:

   `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5`

   Only one IP (10.0.0.10):

   `host    all             all             10.0.0.10/32            md5`
3. Change firewall settings on the server to allow connections to port 5432.